# Invalid displacement location error React Native Expo Bare

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am currently using Expo Location, and whenever I allow location permissions, I get this error. I am on Expo Bare, SDK 47, React 18.1, React Native 0.70.5. Can anyone help me out please? Thank you. [Invalid Displacement Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FMdt.jpg)

I have tried to use another location library, and the result is the same as soon as I enable location permissions.I also made a brand new Expo Bare project and tried this out, and I still get the same error.

Comment: Hi Strawberry, do you find any solutions for this?. Currently also experience invalid displacement when I allow the location permission.

Comment: I have not found anything unfortunately....what versions are you running of React and Expo? Also did it work for you before and you all of a sudden got this issue? Mine used to work perfectly even 2 weeks ago, but this problem came up suddenly out of no where.

Comment: Yes same scenario with you. 2 week or 3 weeks then. suddenly today. I came up no where also. I tried to downgrade, reinstall new project. then If I use the allow permission I got invalid displacement

Comment: May I ask if you are getting location coordinates and displaying them on a map? If so, can I ask what map library you are using?

Comment: Exactly you're correct. I want to get the current location. then displaying on a map. Currently I am using mapbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also facing this error since Monday. I didn't change anything on the code. It crashes when I asked permissions to use the Location.

After several atempts to solve the issue, I figure out rnmapbox released a new version 6 days ago and they have touched the Location Classes.

I downgrade the rnmapbox to 10.0.0-beta.64 at seems to work now. Let me know if it also works for you,

https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps/tree/v10.0.0-beta.64

Good luck

Comment: Thanks Bruno for this feedback, Let me try this recommendation first and I will update you.

Comment: How do you downgrade your mapbox btw?

Comment: I deleted my node_modules folder. Then on the command prompt executed this

`npm i @rnmapbox/maps@10.0.0-beta.64 --save`

Comment: It was definitely a mapbox issue. I downgraded and it works now, thank you!